# REST Vs SOAP API for Email Content Creation in ExactTarget

Tags: email, soap, marketing-cloud, rest

This might be a newbie question, but here it goes anyway

The Web Service  Guide talks about Creating Email content using Web Services API (http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/simple_development_scenarios/creating_an_email/). Both examples seem to use SOAP. Is there a REST API for doing this?

Also, can anyone point out resources for integrating ExactTrgaet with node.js?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do the answers below provide enough to answer your question?  If so, would you mind marking them answered?  If not, please add comments so we can make sure your question is answered.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a possibility for this, it's called the [Fuel API](https://code.exacttarget.com/api) and can be found at code.exacttarget.com

There's also a github project to interact with the [ExactTarget API using node.js](https://github.com/ExactTarget/node-fuel)

Comment: Welcome Sandeep!

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is not a way to create emails utilizing the REST API. This is only currently available through the SOAP API.